# IPA doesn't include UDID that I just added

Tags: ios, xcode, applet, provisioning-profile, ipa

I want to deliver a IPA to a client

I ask him to add his iphone udid on console developper apple, I generate a new IPA, but this IPA doesn't include the UDID he just added.

[image: i don"t have here the udid i just added]

I also see that provising profile are expired (I don't have the admin role to renew them ) it could be this expired that cause me problem ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Include your UDID to Development provisional certificate and update your it in your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anytime you add/remove a device on apple developer portal, you probably want to update the provisioning profiles as well. Once the provisioning profiles have been updated, you can download them and install on your machine. Alternatively, if you're using the same Apple Id with your XCode, you can just check `Automatically manage signing` for your app's target

Comment: Just want to note that there is no "probably" about needing to update the provisioning profile.  That is the only way (short of using automatic code signing) to get the provisioning profile to allow builds to run on the new device.

Comment: Automatic code signing is exactly the reason I used the word probably to save extensive explanation

Comment: A clearer, explanations would be "If you are doing manual code signing, you **must** update the provisioning profile when you add or remove devices"  If you add/remove a device from the developer portal, you aren't using automatic code signing.

Answer (score 1):

After adding new UDID you have to generate new Provisioning Profile. Please check that this new Provisioning Profile include that UDID.

Comment: thanks for your responses, the problem is that Provisioning Profile is expired so i can't download it

Answer (score 1):

The other answers provide some context to the problem, but I wanted to clarify to make sure everyone is clear.  The Provisioning Profile being expired **is NOT the real problem**.  The real problem is that you don't seem to have added the device to the provisioning profile and then re-downloaded it.

In order to get a provisioning profile to be valid for a new device, you need to add the UDID in the Apple developer site, then edit the provisioning profile, adding the newly registered device to that provisioning profile.  After updating the provisioning profile, you need to download it to your Mac and replace the old provisioning profile.